# Wie schreibt man eine gute Antwort?

Tags: support, answers, community-wiki

Man findet sehr viel Diskussion darum, wie man das Stellen von Fragen positiv beeinflussen kann, allerdings fehlt mir eine Anleitung für gute Antworten. Wie sehen gute Antworten aus, was sollten sie enthalten und wie detailliert sollten sie sein? Ich denke mir, daß es eine bestimmte Form und Struktur geben kann, die sinnvoll ist und den Antwortenden helfen kann.

Comment: Hier wäre ein Startpunkt dazu: https://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 3):

Eine gute Antwort sollte folgende Struktur haben:

**Kurze Beantwortung der Kernfrage**

**Begründung**

**Beispiele**

**Verweise auf ähnliche Fragen, Verweise auf Referenzen mit Hilfe von Links**

**Betrachtungen, weiterführende Hinweise, Persönlicher Kommentar**